# pixeled map matplot to "smooth map"?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, netcdf4

rendering a map with `netcdf` information i have the image below but it's pixeled, is there a form to render a "smooth map" like the second image?

```py
#Variables netcdf file
lons = ds.variables['longitude'][:]
lats = ds.variables['latitude'][:]
time = ds.variables['time'][:]
data = ds.variables['tc_ch4'][:]

#map Basemap
mp = Basemap(projection = 'merc',
             llcrnrlon = -95.030665,
             llcrnrlat = 5.2,
             urcrnrlon = -72.960931,
             urcrnrlat = 18.961754,
             resolution = 'i')

lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
x, y = mp(lon, lat)

cscheme = mp.pcolor(x, y, np.squeeze(data[1,:,:]), cmap = 'YlOrRd')
cbar = mp.colorbar(cscheme, location = 'right')
mp.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.3)
mp.drawstates(linewidth=0.1)
mp.drawcountries(linewidth=0.1)
fecha = t[i].strftime('%Y-%m')
plt.title('Columna Total de Metano - kg m**-2')
plt.xlabel('Año-Mes 2003-01')    
plt.show()
```

Image generated with the code above

[image]

Image generated with [**Panoply**](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/)

[image]

Comment: Check this https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html

Comment: http://earthpy.org/interpolation_between_grids_with_basemap.html